# How can I change a &mut Peekable<I> into a &[u8]?

Tags: rust

I have a value with type `&mut Peekable<I>` and I want to use it for input value for other function which gets the value with type `&[u8]`. How can I change the type of it?

Answer (score 2):

`Peekable<I>` is an iterator that gives elements from an iterator that it wraps (with a twist that you can peek one ahead, but that is not relevant here).

`&[u8]` is a slice of bytes laid out contiguously in memory.

So you have two problems:

1. The iterator `I` could be anything. Assuming you got `I` from a generic context, like `foo<I: Iterator>()`, you need to ensure that the iterator gives `u8`, or something convertible to `u8`.
2. The data behind `Peekable` doesn't have to exist in memory. It could be created from a range for example `(0..1000)` or iterating over a `HashMap` which has data scattered in a random fashion. You need to copy it to a vector that guarantees contiguous layout.

First, you'll need to declare you want `u8` with `where I: Iterator<Item=u8>`, or require that the type is convertible to `u8` with `where I: Iterator<Item=impl Into<u8>>`. Then you'll be able to do `let iterator = iterator.map(|el| el.into())` to get an iterator of `u8` elements.

And once you have that, you can collect them into a vector, and get a slice of the vector:

```rust
let vec: Vec<u8> = iterator.collect();
let slice = &vec[..];
```